# How to use a Bootstrap html/css page with a react.js webapp?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

I did generate a single page html file using a Bootstrap 5 generator tool (https://generator.ws/).
This tool is quite flexible, and produces a result which is very close to my needs (you can see a preliminary example [here](https://marcolino.github.io/)).
Unfortunately the tool is not yet compatible with React.
I'd like to integrate the generated html with a simple and standard react.js web app (`npx create-react-app my-app`), to be able to use the react toolchain, and to add some dynamic content (avoiding jquery, of course... :-))

So I ask if it is possible to someway use standard html instead of JSX in the react app.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <body>
      <div id="root"></div>
    </body>

ReactDOM.render(your_html_code_here, document.getElementById('root'));
```

So, as you can see, you can add any html code in your JSX. but this approach is contrary to the concept of react component approach where any dom element is a component
Also, you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-to-react package.

Comment: Yes, the first approach is not what I want, since it keeps html and react completely detached...  
I'm studying html-to-react package now, to see if it implements what I need..